# Dynamic numerical series

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, for-loop, simplify

I am trying to create a program to print first `200` elements following a specific numerical series condition which is

```
1-1-3-6-8-8-10-20
```

But instead of showing, just `200` elements is showing `802`. I assume is because of the code inside the `for` loop. I have hours thinking on how to reduce that code to the job and I cannot think anything else. I am getting frustrated and need your help.

The exercise is on the code comments

```
//Print the following numerical series 1-1-3-6-8-8-10-20  until 200

#include <stdafx.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int Num1=200, z = 0, x = 1, y = 1;

    cout << "\n\n1,";
    cout << " 1,";

    for (int i = 1; i <= Num1; i++)
    {
        z = y + 2;
        cout << " " << z << ","; //It will print 3
        z = z * 2;
        cout << " " << z << ",";//It will print 6
        z = z + 2;
        cout << " " << z << ",";//It will print 8
        z = z;
        cout << " " << z << ",";//It will print 8
        y = z;
    }
    cout << "\n\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could save yourself a lot of time by using a debugger.  Single step through your code, and view the values in variables.

Comment: BTW, the statement `z = z;` has no effect and the compiler probably optimized it away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I assume is because of the code inside the "for" loop but I've hours
>   thinking on how to reduce that code to the job and I cannot think
>   anything else. I'm getting frustrated and need your help.

So you basically wanna simplify your code. Which can be done by noticing the repetitions.
There you can find only two types of change in the series; either a `+2` or `x2` with the previous element.

In each iteration this can be achieved by:

1. If  reminder `i%4 == 1` or `i%4 == 3`, need an increment of 2 (assuming `1 <= i <= MAX`)
2. If reminder `i%4 == 0`, nothing but a multiplication of 2.

When you do like so, you can simply neglect, printing of first two ones and other complications in the total numbers in the series.

Also not that, you are trying to get 200 terms of this series, which increases in each step very fast and exceed the maximum limit of `int`. Therefore, `long long` is needed to be used instead.

The updated code will look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
typedef long long int int64;
int main()
{
    int size = 200;
    int64 z = -1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++)
    {
        if ((i % 4 == 1) || (i % 4 == 3))   z += 2;
        else if (i % 4 == 0)                z *= 2;
        std::cout << z << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

See the Output here: https://www.ideone.com/JiWB8W

Comment: I do appreciate the fact that you took the time to explain me a different way to understand what the loop for needs to accomplish. I'm still trying to understand how this codes gets the second number 1 because z=-1 and then it increments on +2 which will be 1,3 . Do I always needs to use long when the iterations are that high on the loop for?

Comment: You're a genius , I do understand better how the duplicate values are being populated and the correct data type for my variables :)

Answer (score 5):

You're looping 200 times, and each time you loop, you're printing out 4 different numbers. You're also printing twice at the start so thats 2 + 4 * 200 = 802, which is where your 802 number output is coming from.

Comment: I understand that part but what I do not know how to to is just to put 1 code inside the for loop to do all the calculation. The first 2 numbers are the same, then the second number needs to be +2, then the 3rd number x2 , then the 4th number +2 and 5th number is the same as 4th , once this gets completed it will restart to the point that needs to start doing the +2,x2 (This is what I do not know how to do it inside the loop for)

Comment: I assume this is a homework problem or something along those lines, so this isn't really the place to get people to do it for you, but anyway a simple solution is just to solve that short equation in the above answer for num1, i.e.
2 + (4 * num1) = 200

Comment: @JoshSama you are printing 4 numbers 200 times. 4*200 = 800 numbers. So if you want to print 200 numbers how many times the loop should be executed? That's basic school maths.

Comment: My apologizes , my intention is not to get the full exercise completed by someone else , I'm new on c++ and I've built the code from scratch but I was looking for suggestions because my knowledge was not enough to figure out how to do a function inside the loop for,  appreciate your answer and I'll try to use your response to build the code I need. Thank you

Comment: @Michael , the code in the loop was to test how the final data will look , I know from the begging that it will have more than 200 . I was just looking for any idea how to do what does 4 code lines do by using any other stament